# Using Google adsense on phpbb3 web board

Tags: php, html, ads, adsense, phpbb3

I'm trying to include an ad bar at the bottom of my web board.  I'm currently using the open source phpbb3 web forum. I would like to display the ad in the overall_footer.html file so that it appears on every page, but I am getting an error.

Link to my forum with error on bottom of page.
https://50.97.99.170:8443/sitepreview/http/uta-ianmiller.edu/phpbb3/index.php?sid=7d1a7a17add3e8c9d2895eba4c632bb3

I simply cut and pasted the adsense code provided by Google into the site html and I'm getting this error. anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What error are you getting? It works fine for me - I see a banner (similar to ones I've seen on other sites while browsing around the web)

Comment: yeap sure, it also works for me, there is banner on the footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get to your site but if you need to look at some other code, here's my phpbb3 forum that incorporates adsense. Just run developer tools on it.

http://forum.localdives.info